# Кодировка Java (java.util.Scanner)

Tags: java, utf-8, кодировка, scanner

Приветсвую всех!

Cразу по больному месту пройдусь:

Имеется вот такой простейший вид исходного кода:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));

        System.out.println("привет");

        String usrAns = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");

        while( ! usrAns.equals("exit")) {

            usrAns = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(usrAns);
        }

        try {

             in.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Параметры для javac и jvm такие:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 *.java
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 App
```

На моей машине вывод выглядит так:

```
en_US
UTF-8
привет
```

Теперь, собственно, сама проблема:
**При попытке ввести в консоль предложения, написав их на русской раскладке, - выводятся просто символы: ?????**

Вот так:

```
en_US
UTF-8
привет
как проект?
??? ?????
да норм завтра сдача
?? ??? ????? ??
```

jvm стоит на машине с win10 (лицензия как обновление с 8.1 до 10 ставилась):

- Host Name:                 Asus K73SV
- OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- OS Version:                10.0.15063 N/A Build 15063
- OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
- System Type:               x64-based PC
- System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
- Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
- Time Zone:                 (UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd

интерфей ОС англоязычный... даже при переходе на рускоязычную локализацию (ru_RU cp1251) проблемы теже...

Что скажете по такому капризному поведению ?

Comment: разве вопрос к вводимой кодировке не к консоли ?

Comment: Мб, тогда какие варианты ?

Comment: powershell или просто cmd?

Comment: cmd .....................

Comment: только поправка к проблеме: пишу в консоль русские символы --> нажимаю enter --> и в этом случае на консоль выводятся символы: **??????**

Comment: проблема в code page

Comment: Вывел через **Charset.availableCharsets()** доступные кодировочные таблицы - список из 170 наименований (от Big5 до x-windows-iso2022jp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в установленной кодовой странице.
Для поддержки русского текста поменяйет страницу для текущей консоли:

```
chcp 1251
```

Для поддержки UTF-8:

```
chcp 65001
```

Можете выставить в реестре кодовою страницу по умолчанию:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"AutoRun"="chcp 1251"
```

[Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500)
[How to set default charset in Windows cmd?](https://superuser.com/questions/482018/how-to-set-default-charset-in-windows-cmd)
[Кодовая страница](https://www.wikiwand.com/ru/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Comment: Ура! Спасибо большое за направление!