# Кодировка java.util.Scanner

Tags: кодировка, visual-studio-code, utf-8

столкнулся с проблемой кодировки текста, который сохраняет обьект класса Scanner.

Пример простого кода сравнения сохраненного значения и заранее прописанного:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner cons = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = cons.nextLine();
    System.out.println(text);
    if (text.equals("р")) {
        System.out.println("right");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("wrong");
    }
  }
}
```

Он должен сравнить вписанное значение с русской "р", которую прописываю используемой кодировкой, и выводить входную строку.

Проблема в том, что right никогда не выдает, а при выводе вводимого символа пустота или знак вопроса(зависит от кодировки). Пробовал запускать с кодировками UTF-8, UTF-16, Windows 1252, Windows 1251. Пробовал также менять кодировку системы через панель управления на UTF-8, но результата нет.

Пишу код в Visual Studio Code, но при запуске через терминал происходит то же самое.

Версия JDk - 21

ОС Windows 10

Comment: Консоль `Win + R` -> `cmd` или `powershell` имеет кодировку cp866 (исторически так сложилось). Нужно выставлять 65001 для вывода utf8 [Попробуйте применить изменения из этого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696843/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-java-java-util-scanner)

Comment: Дубликат: [В VS Code выводятся знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы после ввода в программе на Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1565483/)

Comment: @MrFylypenko, это достаточно популярная проблема, связанная именно с VS Code и её внутренним терминалом.  Проще перейти на нормальную среду разработки типа IntelliJ Idea, Community Edition вполне достаточно.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, рассматривал решения из этого примера, не помогло. Все равно спасибо за ответ

Comment: @NowhereMan, во внутреннем терминале Idea работает, но меня волнует больше терминал powershell. Не могу ведь только через idea запускать. Если есть проблема, то было бы неправильно от нее абстрагироваться. К тому же у VS Code не внутренний терминал, а вывод из powershell, который есть и в idea. Говоря иначе, проблема не в VS Code